# Why is this MySQL UPDATE query taking so long?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the following code:

```
UPDATE cm_object 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT T1.pandbouwjaar,T.key_id 
           FROM (SELECT cm_object.key_id,build_year,zipcode,housenumber,housenumber_addition 
                 FROM cm_object 
                 LEFT JOIN cm_key 
                   on cm_object.key_id = cm_key.key_id
                 ) T 
                 LEFT JOIN (SELECT pandbouwjaar,postcode,huisnummer,huisnummertoevoeging 
                            FROM avm_new 
                            GROUP BY  postcode,huisnummer,huisnummertoevoeging
                            ) T1 
                  on T.housenumber = T1.huisnummer 
                 AND T.zipcode = T1.postcode 
                 AND T.housenumber_addition = T1.huisnummertoevoeging
           ) T2 
  on T2.key_id = cm_object.key_id 
SET cm_object.build_year = T2.pandbouwjaar
WHERE cm_object.build_year IS NULL;
```

I am trying to join two tables cm_object and cm_key. By using the id from cm_key I need to obtain data related to cm_object

Next, I am using the joined table then to link with another table(avm_new) and extract a column from that.

Using that column values, I want to update the build_year column in cm_object

The primary key and indexes have been assigned for all the columns that is being used. Some of the tables have over 8 million records. But the query is taking really long to finish(more than an hour). Why is this happening? Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: Subqueries can be inefficient in MySQL `from` clauses.  You should describe what you are trying to do and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why is this happening? Because there's a lot of I/O being involved. Is there a way to optimize it? Yes, there is. Since there's no other information form your side, I don't think you can get a better answer than that.

Comment: Sorry. But I have updated with more information above.

Comment: Why do you have a group by in the 3rd nested query w/o any aggregration?  Do you want the min/max/avg pandbouwjaar?

Comment: Because it's a really terrible query

Comment: Also I think if you move/copy your `WHERE cm_object.build_year IS NULL` to the inner query you'll not have to build as large a data set; which you don't use most of.   `...AND T.housenumber_addition = T1.huisnummertoevoeging WHERE cm_object.build_year is null`  As it stands you're joining all records from cm_object when all you really need are the ones with a null build year.

Comment: @xQbert I want to group them so that I can get the bouwjaar for the matching postcode, huisnummer and huisnummertoevging.

Comment: @keshava but if postcode, huisnummer and huisnummertoevging have more than one pandbouwjaar then which one should the system pick?  if they always only have one then a distinct is cleaner as it better defines your intent and in mySQL sometimes faster.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to SQL so I am just starting to familiarize myself with it. 
@zQbert Okay. I will use distinct and move the WHERE query as well.

Comment: Any more suggestions on how to approach this and changes to make would be appreciable. I am still learning so it would be most welcome :)